# How to change local time without using date

Tags: linux, bash, timezone, clock, zoneinfo

It's a remote server so no GUI or fancy stuff installed, I connect to that host using SSH.
For security reasons I suppose, I cannot use the 'date -s' command to change the local server's current time.

```
$ cat /etc/issues ==> Ubuntu 10.04 LTS
$ uname -r ==> 2.6.32-042stab037.1
$ cat $SHELL ==> /bin/bash
```

'date' shows me time that is about 10 minutes early, I tried linking the right time from /usr/share/zoneinfo (New york in my case) to /etc/localtime, but nothing really changed, my clock is still 10 minutes unsynchronized.

Do I have to generate a new time zone binary using zic? Yes? how? no? What else could I try ?

Thanks a bunch in advance.
/s

Answer (score 3):

Did you think about installing a [ntp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol) daemon to keep your time synchronized to avoid those time slicing ?
[Ntpd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ntpd) is a good starting point (it is provided in debian packages **ntp** and **openntpd**)

You'll have to set a server reference (usually ntp.pool.org, but you can change it if you need) and then, launch it on machine startup.... and let him do the job (ie : keep the time synchronized)

Comment: sudo ntpdate -u [server] results in "Operation not permitted".

Comment: ntpdate is NOT the same thing as using the ntp daemon.  You need to turn on the ntp service, and define a time server.  Besides which using date or ntpdate can really screw up OS-time related things when the system is off substantially.

Answer (score 3):

Use `adjtimex(8)` to set the system clock of a running system. It will smoothly adjust the time and not leave any scary gaps as `date` would. The syntax for using it is quite beyond me, however, so I just use ntp and forget it.

If your clock issues persists accross reboots you will need to reset the hardware clock with `hwclock` as well.